# Insertar datos en una base de datos externa Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy creado una aplicación y necesito guardar datos en otra base de datos que no es la habitual en el proyecto.

He creado el archivo .env con la nueva conexión y consulto datos de la base de datos externa sin ningún problema, pero a la hora de insertar un nuevo registro en esa tabla no se muy bien como proceder.

Consulto los registros de la otra base de datos así:

```
$categorias = DB::connection('depildiodo')->table('categoria_blogs')->get();
```

Eso funciona bien, pero para guardar datos en esa tabla externa? Normalmente utilizo Eloquent:

```
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo = new Event;
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->foto = $request->input('imagen');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->titulo = $request->input('titulo');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->subtitulo = $request->input('subtitulo');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->cuerpo = $request->input('cuerpo');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->id_usuario = $request->input('id_usuario');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->id_categoria = $request->input('id_categoria');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->fecha = $request->input('fecha');
    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->estado = $request->input('estado');


    $addNoticiaDepildiodo->save();
```

Pero en este caso como seria??

**Intento de JOIN con tabla interna con externa**

```
$noticias = DB::connection('depildiodo')->table('noticias')
          ->join('categoria_blogs', 'noticias.id_categoria', '=', 'categoria_blogs.id')
          ->leftjoin('users', 'noticias.id_usuario', '=', 'users.id')
          ->select('noticias.*', 'users.name AS nombreRedactor', 'categoria_blogs.valor')->get();
```

Pero no me devuelve `users.name AS nombreRedactor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas un modelo de laravel, le tienes que especificar a que base de datos se tiene que conectar, esto lo puedes hacer declarando la variable `$connection` en el modelo

```
protected $connection = 'depildiodo';
```

al igual puedes hacerlo con query builder.

```
DB::connection('depildiodo')->table('categoria_blogs')->insert(array(
   'foto' => $request->input('imagen'),
   ...
));
```

**Edicion**

Como opción, puedes omitir el atributo `$connection` en el modelo y usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$addNoticiaDepildiodo = new Event;
$addNoticiaDepildiodo->on('depildiodo');
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona perfectamente. 2 pregunta, la primera por que hay que declararlo? y de este modo no introduce los `timestamps` @tecnobyte

Comment: Llos modelos toman la conexion a la base de datos por defecto, en la configuracion del archivo database.php de laravel esta el atributo default, ese es la conexion que se toma si no se especificas una nueva conexion a otra db.

Comment: Hola @BetaM si correcto ese modelo siempre va a conectar a la base de datos depildiodo, pero si la declaro puedo hacer la insercción de otro modo? de que sirve? porque al insertarlos así no introduce en el registro los `timestamps`

Comment: Si correcto, insertando el registro con `new Noticia` al final pones el save, pero al hacerlo como dice el compañero es nuevo para mi, no se por que no guarda ese valor

Comment: Claro esque al ser una BD externe no tengo ese modelo en este proyecto.. es necesario? y se puede hacer un JOIN con una tabla externa con una interna @BetaM. ??

Comment: Como lo tienes en un consulta get para obtener datos de la tabla categoria_blogs, puedes usar join sin problemas, solo le especificas las tablas que puedes usar y listo.

Comment: pero @tecnobyte ese ultimo modo que pones es el que busco, pero claro no tengo modelo en esta app de la bd externa, entonces donde pone `Event` no podria poner nada no?

Comment: si quieres usar eloquen, si necesitas tener el modelo creado.

Comment: Mira edite mi pregunta de como estoy haciendo el join @tecnobyte pero no me devuelve `users.name AS nombreRedactor`

Comment: Puede ser en leftjoin, si te trae nulos trata de pasar el leftjoin arriba del primer join o puede ser que no tengas datos las tablas relacionadas.

Comment: Me sigue trayendo null el nombre del redactor, he probado con el `leftjoin` pero del mismo modo pasa lo mismo. Ya he creado el modelo y todo como decias y funciona genial, me es más facil entenderlo así, pero no se como hacer que funcione el join @tecnobyte

Comment: Tienes razón @BetaM voy a ello, gracias!